# why does my edge console shows net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when I try to upload background image?

Tags: html, css, image

My image is not showing up i dont know why.

In my edge browser in the console it is showing - net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
I know my code is lil bit messy
but im on this problem since 3 days

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/blanka" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
  <title>xxxx</title>
  <body>
    <style>
    p{
        background-image: url("E:\xxxx\Images\FinLax.png");
    }
</style>
  </body>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fin">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">xxxx</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</body>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hire Tale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Make Moy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Why xxxx</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url('E:\\xxxx\FinLax.png');
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }
.fin {
    font-family: 'Blanka', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate( -715%, -550%);
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate( -43%, -100%);
  }
  
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    color: #1520A6;
  }
  ul li a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000,
                0 -1px 0 0 #000;
    transform: scaleY(2.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  ul li a:hover::before {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  ul li a:hover::after {
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

I tried right path to the image and everything .
help me

Comment: Users of your website are rather unlikely to have direct access to your `E:` drive; don't try to use that in a web url.  You're going to want to put that image somewhere inside your webroot (i.e. in the same folder as your index.html or in some child folder of that) and use a url based on its location compared to webroot (i.e. if you put it in a child folder named "images", use `url('/images/FinLax.png')`.

Comment: Thanks man but I tried that still not working .

Comment: That gives us very little information to work with.   If you have the file path correct, it should work.  If you don't, it won't.   There's not much more anyone here can do without knowing where you've put your files or what specifically you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using is not valid.

If you're opening your HTML file locally, then the path should start with a protocol `file`. E.g. like this:

```
file:///E:/xxxx/Images/FinLax.png
```

Note: the slashes also have been changed.

Or, you may use relative path. E.g. if your HTML file is `E:/xxxx/index.html`, then the path to the image will be:

```
./Images/FinLax.png
```

In this case browser fill use the protocol with that you've opened your file.

Please note, you can't use `file` protocol if you're serving your file from a real server with real domain. Use it only when you open your HTML file locally.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. I even tried that.     In my web browser it is showing console net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND